# How to restrict a user or a group of users to access an asset in fatwire

Tags: content-management-system, fatwire

How to restrict a user or a group of users to access an asset in fatwire
I wanted to obtain standard mvc functionality using fatwire.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an attribute to the flexasset definition to establish wich users (groups much better) have access to the asset. In your template, before rendering, check if the user (group) have access and, if so, render the asset.

Comment: Is there any easier way like the users and access in mvc

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how to restrict users/groups from accessing assets in Fatwire authoring screen? We can achieve this through multiple ways such as site as the secure scope and assign users/groups to the sites. Users can only see assets available in the logged in site.

If you need users to collaborate within the same site, you can create a one-step workflow and add all sites to the workflow and assign certain users/groups to the workflow.